# Sincronizar IDs do ListView com banco de dados

Tags: android

Estou trabalhando em um projeto para a faculdade no qual uso um banco de dados e uma ListView. O problema se dá quando preciso recuperar os dados de um dos itens da ListView, pois não consigo sincronizar os IDs da ListView com os IDs do BD. No caso, se eu cadastro alguns itens no BD e depois os removo, os IDs da ListView não correspondem mais aos do BD, fazendo com que dê erro na hora de remover ou visualizar.

Existe alguma maneira de amarrar os itens da ListView a um ID único, que não altere caso a ordem ou a quantidade de itens da ListView mude?

Comment: Como assim `não consigo sincronizar os IDs da ListView com os IDs do BD`?

Comment: Se eu crio 2 itens, no BD eles ficam cadastrados como 1 e 2. Na ListView fica como 0 e 1. Até aí é tranquilo, mas quando eu apago o item 0, por exemplo, o item que era 1 passa a ter ID 0, impossibilitando recuperar os dados do BD.

Comment: Utilize o cursorAdapter, e sempre que excluir um elemento da lista, recarregue-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependendo dos itens que tens na `ListView` o melhor seria ter mesmo objetos associados. Ou seja, cada item da lista seria um objeto e esse objeto teria o ID vindo da Base de Dados.

```
public class Objeto{

private int ID;
private ...;
...;
}
```

Depois teria de criar um Adptador de **Objecto** com o override de getPosition(Objeto o)

```
public class AdaptadorObjeto extends ArrayAdapter<Objeto> {

    @Override
    public int getPosition(Objeto o) {
        return super.getPosition(o);
    }
}
```

A partir dai e através da posição atual, do toque poderá fazer o que quiser com o elemento, podendo apagar da base de dados porque tem o ID do mesmo.

Fonte [Android ArrayAdpter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Meu projeto já usa um objeto para popular a ListView. Só não entendi completamente a parte do override. Onde eu coloco esse código? Dentro da classe que define meu objeto?

Comment: Podes por o código de como preenches a `ListView`?

Comment: Claro:
`ArrayAdapter<Evento> eventos;
eventos = new ArrayAdapter<Evento>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bd.lerEventos());
setListAdapter(eventos);`

Comment: E como vais "buscar" o item a lista para apagar?

Comment: Acho que aí reside o maior problema, pois preciso de uma nova `Activity` para realizar tal operação (requisito do trabalho). No caso, faço um bundle dentro do `onListItemClick` e passo os dados para outra activity:
`Bundle info = new Bundle();
Evento selecionado = bd.lerEvento(position + 1);
...
info.putInt("posicao", position + 1);

Intent visualizar = new Intent(this, Tela_Visualizacao.class);
visualizar.putExtras(info);
startActivity(visualizar);`

Comment: Na outra activity fica assim: `posicao = dados.getInt("posicao");
public void removerEvento(int posicao) {
BancoDeDados bd = new BancoDeDados(this);
Evento praRemover = bd.lerEvento(posicao);
bd.apagarEvento(praRemover);
finish();
}`

Comment: Tu dentro do `onListItemClick` tens de ir buscar o Evento, exemplo:

`Evento ev = (Evento) listviw.getItemAtPosition(position);`

A partir dai já podes saber qual o id do evento, tipo: `ev.getID()`;

Mas em principio terás mesmo de ter um Adptador de Evento como te tinha dito na resposta.

Comment: Tens [aqui](http://mobgeek.com.br/blog/exibir-itens-lista-android) um exemplo básico.

Comment: Cara, só usando o `.getItemAtPosition(position);` já funcionou! Parou de dar erro, imagino que não precisarei usar o código que me disse. Muito obrigado!